# nodejs Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I have a node server :

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(4000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var cookie_reader = require('cookie');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var redis = require('redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();

//Subscribe to the Redis chat channel
sub.subscribe('chat');

//Configure socket.io to store cookie set by Django
io.configure(function(){
    io.set('authorization', function(data, accept){
        if(data.headers.cookie){
            data.cookie = cookie_reader.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error', false);
    });
    io.set('log level', 1);
});
```

When I run this it gives error `Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'`
I searched for it but not found any particular solution.

Whats wrong in here ??

Comment: [This document](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/configuring-socket.io) might imply that you need to install express, maybe for dependencies. But the document is valid for Socket.IO v0.9 and lower. Which version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is for `socket.io@0.9.x` and you have installed version `1.0` or later. You need to either downgrade (`npm install socket.io@0.9.17`) or, preferably, [upgrade your codebase to use latest version](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/).